# Reinforcement Learning, how to tweak recommendation system

Tags: reinforcement-learning

A recommendation system is running on real time. It can suggest 3 products for say x,y,z. But for today's data it is only giving out product x all the time. What has to be tweaked. Any solution in terms of reinforcement learning ?

Comment: Before anyone can help, you should provide more detail, for example: name or type of recommendation engine. What is the typical recommendation and what is coming out today, esp. the literal recommendation (JSON, XML, etc. ?) And then, whats the difference in today's data flow?

Comment: sorry, couldn't provide details on the type of recommendation engine used. I was asked this question in an interview, I assumed there might be skewness in the today's data as it keeps recommending single/same product all day. But wasn't sure of my answer.